# Github compare commits vs current on local

Tags: github

Is there a way to compare committed versions vs currently what's on local?

Sample scenario:
Created a file named file.txt

```
first content
```

`git add file.txt` -> `git commit`

Then updated the file.txt to

```
first content
second content
```

Without committing the second content, can I view the diff between the last commit vs what's currently on local machine?

something like `diffcommit file.txt` and will show

```
< first content
---
> first content
> second content
```

Comment: On the go right now... Check out `git diff ...` command. It compares and shows difference  https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff